# OpenFL: inconsistent compile results for different targets

Tags: haxe, openfl

I have the following simple haxe/openfl code, and couldn't figure out why it should compile for one target and fail for others. My understanding is that OpenFL should bring the flash API to all supported languages/platforms.

```
//test.hx
import flash.display.Sprite;
class Test {
  static function main() {
      var g:Sprite = new Sprite();
      g.graphics.drawPath([1, 2], [1.1, 1.2,2.1,2.2]); //problem line
  }
}
```

The compilation is OK when compiled for the neko target:

```
$ haxelib run openfl build project.xml neko
```

However, when compiling it to flash, an error is generated:

```
$ haxelib run openfl build project.xml flash
./Test.hx:5: characters 23-29 : Array<Int> should be flash.Vector<Int>
./Test.hx:5: characters 23-29 : For function argument 'commands'
```

It looks weird to me because from the error message it seems that, for one target the function `drawPath` requires `Array` type arguments and for another target, the same function requires `Vector` typed arguments.

Any idea why this happens, and how to make this work for both targets?

BTW, if I compile this to HTML5, I got:

```
$ haxelib run openfl build project.xml html5
./Test.hx:5: characters 3-22 : flash.display.Graphics has no field drawPath
```

The function don't even exist here. The results above is with Haxe 3.0.1 and the newest openfl as of Feb 2014.

Comment: I don't really understand why your compilation command is "openfl build...", I use "lime build ..." or I'm missing a yet another update? :)

Comment: @CreativeMagic I use `haxelib run openfl build` because that is the command used by FlashDevelop when compiling the OpenFL project. What's the complete command you use? Thanks.

Comment: btw, because I use msys/mingw32, I need to use `haxelib run lime` instead of `lime` everywhere. stackoverflow.com/questions/21837170/

Comment: @tinlyx You might want to mark one of the answers as accepted? :)

Answer (score 1):

OpenFL requires [`openfl.Vector`](http://www.openfl.org/documentation/api/openfl/Vector.html), as seen in [`Graphics.drawPath`](http://www.openfl.org/documentation/api/openfl/display/Graphics.html#drawPath) method signature:

```
public function drawPath (commands:Vector<Int>, data:Vector<Float>, winding:GraphicsPathWinding = null):Void
```

While mac and neko targets accept arrays, Flash requires the OpenFL vector class; also, `drawPath` is not implemented for html5 target.

Therefore, implement commands and data parameters as follows:

```
package;

import openfl.Vector;
import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.display.Graphics;

class Main extends Sprite {

    public function new() {
        super();

        var g:Graphics = graphics;
        g.lineStyle(2, 0x0);

        var commands:Vector<Int> = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2];
        var data:Vector<Float> = [20.0,10.0, 
                                  50.0,10.0,
                                  50.0,40.0, 
                                  20.0,40.0, 
                                  20.0,10.0];
        g.drawPath(commands, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be that your problem exists because you are executing a command:

```
haxelib run openfl build project.xml flash
```

Perhaps you haven't installed the latest OpenFL that runs on LiME (Light Media Engine) or you have an older version of FlashDevelop that builds your app using an older OpenFL version.

I do all my building from the command line manually and now, the new command is:

```
lime build flash
```

And yes, as much as I remember the JS api doesn't have a drawPath method, so no luck there. This could however change by now, but if it didn't, I recommend making a compilation condition for HTML5 and use other methods: draw lines, curves etc.

Look at the OpenFL official web-site for more info - it's written quite well:
http://www.openfl.org/documentation/

Please note, OpenFL is changing very frequently and it's sometimes confusing, because the build commands and dependency packages change a lot. You must always check the current state of OpenFL. I'm pretty sure it will change again in half a year or so.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have just tried `haxelib run lime build {flash,html5,neko}`. The results are the same. Only neko works, flash and html5 fails with the same errors. The openfl version I use was downloaded only a couple of days ago when the question was posted, and it is the latest release.

Comment: I'll check later if the situation improves.